# Execute the same function multiple times in parallel in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

I have a function that I'd like to run multiple times, generating a list of the results:

```
(take 10 (repeatedly #(myfunc)))
```

I realized I could run them in parallel with `pmap`:

```
(pmap (fn [_] (myfunc)) (range 10))
```

But it is a bit untidy. Is there a standard function that lets me do this Something like:

```
(prun 10 #(myfunc))
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in [The Claypoole library](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole) for managing threadpools and parallel processing.  Look at their version of `pmap` and `pfor`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an existing function, but using [`pcalls`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pcalls) rather than `pmap` seems a little closer to what you want:

```
(defn prun [n f]
  (apply pcalls (repeat n f)))
```

You don't need to wrap `myfunc` with `#()` in the call to`repeatedly`, btw, nor calling `prun` as defined above:

```
(prun 10 myfunc)
```

You may find [`pvalues`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pvalues) useful as well.

Comment: Wow, that is precise what I was looking for. Thanks. Didn't come across those calls while looking at the documentation myself.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, Ana.  You may want to upvote and possibly accept.  Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dotimes`

```
(dotimes [_ 10] (myfunc))
```

This will run your function 10 times. Be sure to run this in the same namespace as your function